# VS 2012 Error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm here so I can find a solution for my problem. I know this is too simple, but somehow I can't figure out where's the error in my code!

Here you have it:

AulaData.h

```
#ifndef AULADATA_H_
#define AULADATA_H_
#include <string>
using std::string;


class AulaData 
{
private:
    int dia;


public:
    AulaData(int dia);
};
#endif
```

AulaData.cpp

```
#include "AulaData.h"


AulaData::AulaData(int dia)
{

}
```

And finally, my Main.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include "AulaData.h"
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    AulaData a(12);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

The error I'm getting is the following(something that never happened to me):

> 1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: __thiscall AulaData::AulaData(int)" (??0AulaData@@QAE@XZ)
>   referenced in function _main

Although if I define the class constructor without arguments, it'll work.
I'd appreciate a lot if someone could help me! :) I'm trully getting frustrated because all seems ok. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're not building this correctly. What is the output of the build command?

Comment: Andrew Douglas: here you have the output -> http://pastebin.com/yJ74kUfx

Comment: I don't see AulaData.cpp being complied anywhere

Comment: Andrew Douglas: Looks like it is the class name! I deleted the class and created a random one that is exactly the same and it worked out of the box!

Comment: `AulaData.cpp` is not being compiled. Look at your build log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you must provide a default constructor as well if you create one with arguments.